# Firefox & Chrome don't display image in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I've got a rather simple function that hides some divs used to collect some info and then shows an update message....

```
function updatePleaseWaitingPane() {

    document.getElementById('formDiv').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('furtherQuestions').style.display = "none";
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.setAttribute('id', 'PleaseWaitDiv');
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<h2>Please wait</h2><br/><br/><br/><br/><img src=\"http://www.myurl.com/images/pleaseWait.gif\" alt=\"Please wait\" width=\"600\" height=\"54\"><br/><br/><br/><br/>Thanks for your input. Now let us get you some answers";
    document.getElementById('Content').appendChild(newdiv);
}
```

it all works fine, it is simple, however the image I've injected doesn't seem to load in Chrome of Firefox, but it does in IE? I've checked the URL and when inspecting the element in Firebug the image is displayed with a preview so the URL is correct. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: is this called after the dom is ready?

Comment: why not just have a hidden div that you make visible containing ths info?

Comment: Can you put it on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Could you give us a demo with HTML that demonstrates your issue? It could be just that the <img> tag isn't closed if you're using Strict?

Comment: The dom is ready, I'll try and stick this on fiddle

Comment: Okay, after pulling my hair out (What's remaining that is) I decided to forget injecting/creating a new element and just create the div in the page and hiding it by CSS and then getting JavaScript to display it when a button is clicked. This did create a problem in IE where the image I was now displaying (the pleaseWait.gif) was freezing, so I had to write a condition that if the browser was IE, clear the image and inject an new one using "append". THanks for all your advice.

Answer (score 1):

IE will match `document.getElementById('Content')` against the differently cased `id="content"` whereas Chrome will not, sure the ID is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the image tag

```
<img src="/watever" />
```

^^ note the slash before the closing angle bracket

Comment: Should only matter if the document is XHTML.  Which might be the case, considering all the `<br/>`s, unless someone's just blindly using XHTML syntax (which is not strictly valid in HTML 4, BTW).